# Hyperparameter Optimization Sampling

Tags: sampling, automl

I hope you can help me with your expertise and breadth of knowledge for a problem that I will *try to articulate* as best as possible :) I have a problem that, to my understanding, should be also occurring in AutoML approaches.

**Context:** For an object, I can calculate n (in my case 9) features that determine derived features. One random example would be an image (object) and its features, e.g., how well it can be compressed, or a contrast score, or how many edges can be found, etc. etc.
So far so good, but now the dimensions are not necessarily uncorrelated/linear independent. This could mean that a high value in one dimension can imply a high value in another dimension or a low value or constraint the value ranges. Illustrative example: An image that can be poorly compressed is showing most likely a high variance in terms of the color or gradients. *(I'm totally making this up)*.

**Problem:** Now imagine that I want to *"learn" an object generator, which can produce all these objects for me depending on the location in the (derived) HD feature space*. Side note, this question is **NOT which ML model** (GAN, variational autoencoders, or some other AI models, you name it) can be used for this problem. My challenge is to ensure that I have "captured" the entire functional feature space for the AI model learning step. **But, how can I be certain that I have sampled the space (enough) if I'm not even clear how the functional dependencies are between the dimensions look like?** On top of that, even if I had the correlation scores between the dimensions, which insane mathematical optimizer takes this as an input to tell me how the HD space "looks like"?

A *rather vague* mathematical description of the problem would be that I have an n-dimensional feature space, whose dimensions do not form an orthonormal basis. The dimensions are, ergo, not (necessarily) linear independent, and their dependencies cannot easily/fully derived. How can I (experimentally) determine the possible solution space? Which mathematical problem shares (at least some) similarities? Which math, ML, AI subdiscipline deals with those kinds of problems?

One more thing: I don't expect full-fledged a solution of any sort, but only pointers.

THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered demensionality reduction? If it is linear relationships you are particularly interested in you could consider eigenvalue decomposistion (or principle component analysis if you prefer the term). This might help identify the reachable subspace of your feature space.

More advance dimensionality reduction methods exists as well that are able to hanle non-linear dependencies between features as well. One example is using an autoencoder ANN.